# How can I solve the integral in the error function $\mbox{erf}(x)$?

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion, error-function

To get from this

[image: from this]

To this series
[image: to this]

I can't seem find the step-by-step solution anywhere.

Comment: Your calculus textbook should have information on integrating a power series term-by-term.

Comment: Integrate the series term by term to get a series for your answer.  Then, if you need a "practical" answer, approximate the resulting series with as much precision as you need.

Comment: Is the question how to evaluate $\int \mbox{erf}(t)\,dt$, or is the question how to evaluate $\mbox{erf}(x)$ itself, which is a function defined by an integral?

Comment: @DavidK the error function itself

Comment: @Agustina then your question title is misleading.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the title. Agustina (and everyone else), does that seem like an accurate description of the problem now?

Comment: @DavidK Not quite, I would like to know how can I solve the integral inside [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/3/4/4/3443265ce8cb884d9c894401ab15fa71.png) definition of the error function in order to end up with the series

Answer (score 3):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\int e^{-x^2}\,dx
&=
\int\left\{
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\left(-x^2\right)^{k}
\right\}\,dx \\
&=
\int
\left\{
\sum_{k=0}^\infty
\frac{1}{k!}(-1)^kx^{2k}
\right\}\,dx
\\
&=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{1}{k!}
\left\{
\int x^{2k}\,dx
\right\} \\
&=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty
(-1)^k\frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}
\end{align*}